# Xamarin Json parsing

Tags: json, xamarin.forms

Ι am having a json like this:

```
{"userTweetsList":[{"tweetId":1,"tweetData":"testing uploading from uwp","createdTime":1510822592529,"commentCount":0,"likeCount":1,"flagCount":1,"mediaUrl":"suburl","tweetUser":"geo.thomas","userLiked":true,"userFlagged":true},{"tweetId":2,"tweetData":"Testing tweet","createdTime":1510821224655,"commentCount":0,"likeCount":0,"flagCount":1,"mediaUrl":"suburl","tweetUser":"sreejith.sree","userLiked":false,"userFlagged":true}],"tweetUsersMapList":[{"geo.thomas":{"username":"geo.thomas","name":"geo thomas ","profileImage":null}},{"sreejith.sree":{"username":"sreejith.sree","name":"sreejith sreenivasan","profileImage":null}}],"urlFileserverDynamic":"MyBaseUrl"}
```

My model class:

```
 public class UserTweetResponse
 {
     public List<UserTweetsList> userTweetsList { get; set; }
 }
 public class UserTweetsList
 {
     public int tweetId { get; set; }
     public string tweetData { get; set; }
     public string createdTime { get; set; }
     public int commentCount { get; set; }
     public int likeCount { get; set; }
     public int flagCount { get; set; }
     public string mediaUrl { get; set; }
     public string tweetUser { get; set; }
     public bool userLiked { get; set; }
     public bool userFlagged { get; set; }
      public bool isMediaUrlNull { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaUrl); } }
   }
```

In my cs file, I link the listview with the userTweetsList, My listview name is ListView1.

```
     ListView1.ItemsSource = userTweetResponse.userTweetsList;
```

I can access the all the data in the userTweetsList using {binding} property.

My problem is I need to access and show the name in ui based on the tweet user value. Suppose the "tweetUser":"geo.thomas" i need to access the

```
{"geo.thomas":{"username":"geo.thomas","name":"geo thomas ","profileImage":null}} inside the tweetUsersMapList, same way for "tweetUser":"sreejith.sree"
```

i need the data

```
{"sreejith.sree":{"username":"sreejith.sree","name":"sreejith sreenivasan","profileImage":null}}
```

For this I change the model like this:

```
 public class UserTweetResponse
 {
    public List<UserTweetsList> userTweetsList { get; set; }
    public List<TweetUsersMapList> tweetUsersMapList { get; set; }
 }
 public class UserTweetsList
 {
    public int tweetId { get; set; }
    public string tweetData { get; set; }
    public string createdTime { get; set; }
    public int commentCount { get; set; }
    public int likeCount { get; set; }
    public int flagCount { get; set; }
    public string mediaUrl { get; set; }
    public string tweetUser { get; set; }
    public bool userLiked { get; set; }
    public bool userFlagged { get; set; }
    public bool isMediaUrlNull { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaUrl); } }
  }

 public class TweetUsersMapList
 {
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string profileImage { get; set; }
 }
```

But i don't know how to do the rest part. How can i link the listview with tweetUsersMapList? Based on the tweetUser name how can i pick the name and show that in the ui?
Is it possible to parse this type of complex json?
Anybody, please suggest a solution
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UserTweetsList
{
    public int tweetId { get; set; }
    public string tweetData { get; set; }
    public object createdTime { get; set; }
    public int commentCount { get; set; }
    public int likeCount { get; set; }
    public int flagCount { get; set; }
    public string mediaUrl { get; set; }
    public string tweetUser { get; set; }
    public bool userLiked { get; set; }
    public bool userFlagged { get; set; }
}

public class GeoThomas
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object profileImage { get; set; }
}

public class SreejithSree
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object profileImage { get; set; }
}

public class TweetUsersMapList
{
    public GeoThomas __invalid_name__geo.thomas { get; set; }
    public SreejithSree __invalid_name__sreejith.sree { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<UserTweetsList> userTweetsList { get; set; }
    public List<TweetUsersMapList> tweetUsersMapList { get; set; }
    public string urlFileserverDynamic { get; set; }
}
```

I have used [Json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/#) to generate these classes...